# HTML part not properly render in canvas by using html2canvas function?

Tags: php, jquery, html, canvas, html2canvas

First i convert square image to circle through below code.

```
HTML
<div id="output_image" style="float:right; margin-bottom:6px; margin-right:6px;"><img id="imgdis" class="type3" src="components/com_jumi/files/imagesupload/Chrysanthemum.jpg"></div>

CSS
.type3 {
    width: 187px;
    height: 187px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 46px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 93px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Image size format change successfully. But when i render those part in canvas its not render, its display square image but i want to display circle image.
See below example.

[Orange image is uploaded image. Image format is Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl1uE.png)

[After execute html2canvas function its display in square instead of circle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlQCD.png)

Comment: Which version of html2canvas ? Latest one [does support border-radius](https://jsfiddle.net/6ebphvph/1), maybe not old ones.

Comment: i am using html2canvas v0.33 jQuery. Is it latest?

Comment: Nope, latest is 0.5.0, available [here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases)

Comment: its working new version js